# Почему node в консоли показывает stacktrace с js файлами, а не ts?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Мой ts.config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "gen",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es6", "es2015.promise", "es2015.iterable", "es2015.collection", "es2015.reflect", "es2015.proxy"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots" : ["node_modules/@types"],
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

Когда в консоли смотрю лог с ошибками стектрейс содержит ссылки на js файлы а не ts:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\test\gen\app\www\img\favicon.png'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:1000:11)
    at resolveSync (E:\test\node_modules\serve-favicon\index.js:172:17)
    at favicon (E:\test\node_modules\serve-favicon\index.js:61:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\test\gen\app\App.js:42:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Непонятно почему так, при этом бряки в дебагере работают в ts-файлах.
Подскажите что можно сделать чтоб ссылки в логе были на ts-файлы?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пакет [source-map-support](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support):

> This module provides source map support for stack traces in node via the V8 stack trace API. It uses the source-map module to replace the paths and line numbers of source-mapped files with their original paths and line numbers. The output mimics node's stack trace format with the goal of making every compile-to-JS language more of a first-class citizen.

Достаточно установить пакет:

```
npm install --save source-map-support
```

Затем импортировать модуль:

```
require('source-map-support').install();

// ES6 import
import 'source-map-support/register';
```

Comment: В итоге написал свой плагин для gulp